# List of unused key combinations to be used in AutoHotkey

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Is it possible to determine the list of unused key combinations to be used in AutoHotkey for scripting purposes?

For example Ctrl+Alt+1 is not used in my keyboard

```
^!1::
  ; do something
Return
```

But Ctrl+Alt+2 corresponds to @-sign.

I would like to remap several key combinations in such manner which would not conflict the use of other programs.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, how to do it automatically, then the answer is: obviously no, **you can't do it**, because how on earth could you do it automatically?
If the question is just how to do it, then the answer is simple: you take every application you use 
and notice keys and combinations that you use within those applications, and take care of defining new ones. 
So generally you don't do anything *special* to avoid them, apart from *just avoiding* them.

By default, all AHK hotkeys are system-wide and "blocking". A running AHK script consumes the key event, 
and prevents passing it further to the system (or any other app) and *it is good so*. 
So at worst, you will lose ability to use this shortcut in some other application, and if you still need it there - then it is up to you how to resolve it, there is no single answer here.

One approach to keeping it all under control is to define **application-specific** hotkeys. 
I.e. you can define a hotkey which is processed only when specific condition is met.
See https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context

Comment: "you can't do it, because how could you do it?" is terrible reasoning.  It is quite easy to determine which hotkeys are available for registration: attempt to register them with RegisterHotkey.  If it fails, they're not available.  However, as you've pointed out, AutoHotkey can override registered hotkeys.  It also supports hotkeys which RegisterHotkey doesn't; those are almost certainly available, because very few programs use anything but RegisterHotkey.